# Learning Python - syntax error preventing me from proceeding in tutorial

Tags: python, syntax

As the title suggests I'm doing a tutorial. I have however come across this error:

```
>>> from words import (fetch_words, print_words)
>>> print_words(fetch_words())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jjosey\Documents\pyfund\words.py", line 12, in print_words
    for word in story_words:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

When calling this file (words.py):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def fetch_words():
    with urlopen('http://sixty-north.com/c/t.txt') as story:
        story_words = []
        for line in story:
            line_words = line.decode('utf-8').split()
            for word in line_words:
                story_words.append(word)

def print_words(story_words):               
    for word in story_words:
        print(word)

def main():
    words = fetch_words()
    print_words(words)          

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I understand that the error suggests I'm calling a null array. But this is exactly what the tutor does in the video, so I'm assuming I've made a typo somewhere that's caused the error to hit me. And this is day one of my learning Python, so I'm not spotting it.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `fetch_words` doesn't return anything.

Comment: That is not a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting a `return` statement at the end of `fetch_words`. Without it, `words = fetch_words()` will cause `words` to be `None`.

```
def fetch_words():
    with urlopen('http://sixty-north.com/c/t.txt') as story:
        story_words = []
        for line in story:
            line_words = line.decode('utf-8').split()
            for word in line_words:
                story_words.append(word)
    return story_words
```

Comment: Many thanks. The block of text was quickly converted into a function during the tutorial, and he slipped in the 'return' line without me noticing. That's the culprit. Solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def fetch_words():
    with urlopen('http://sixty-north.com/c/t.txt') as story:
        story_words = []
        for line in story:
            line_words = line.decode('utf-8').split()
            for word in line_words:
                story_words.append(word)
```

This function has a bug... it does not `return` a value, though you try to use the returned value later.  Try this...

```
def fetch_words():
    story_words = []
    with urlopen('http://sixty-north.com/c/t.txt') as story:
        for line in story:
            line_words = line.decode('utf-8').split()
            for word in line_words:
                story_words.append(word)
    return story_words
```